# Better Word for a "Delivery Guy"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the alternative of saying "delivery guy" or "UPS truck driver" if, for example, you are leaving a note and you want to make it sound less menial? I guess you can say "UPS truck operator" but how would you call a "pizza delivery guy"? "Pizza delivery operator" sounds somewhat silly, right?

Comment: What about deliveryman?

Comment: Why bother with anything but the company name: _Dear FedEx_, _Dear Pizza Hut_, _Dear Sears_? There's no need to acknowledge that the delivery person is a person rather than a dog or an android. They know that. You know that. Even your cat & dog know that. Don't step into the quagmire of PC language if you can avoid it, & **you can avoid it** if you try.

Comment: OTOH, you can always take the WalMart approach: **Dear Delivery Associate**. Or you can go all out & say something like _Dear Fellow Human Being So Worthy of My PC Veneer of Respect That I Have to Make a Donkey of Myself Trying to Figure Out What to Call You So That You & My Neighbors Won't Think I'm Some Kind of Arrogant & Offensive Consumer or Whatever_ & feel really really really virtuous & superior to everyone who tends to notice things like gender, age, weight, sunglasses brand, footwear, hairstyle, exhibitionist body piercings, tattoos, & general level of attractiveness. [NB: Humor].

Comment: PC labels serve two purposes: They make the PC cantor feel morally superior, & they dehumanize everybody else.

Comment: @BillFranke's point is good in that a note on the door can just say, ***FedEx - leave pkg behind planter***.  If referring to the person, when we must, however, can be handled with "driver", as I offered in my answer, without tripping over our over-sized PC yokes. :-)

Comment: Alimentation facilitator

Comment: A clause of the union contract stipulates they must be called delivery engineers.

Comment: English major? (I are one, so I can make fun, okay?)

Comment: Generation Xand younger would use the all encompassing "dude"

Comment: Dominos, the major pizza chain in the US, uses the term "delivery driver", which encapsulates both what they do (deliver pizza) and how they do it (drive).  Now, if they had delivery on foot, via bicycle, or using drones, they'd need to come up with a better term.

Comment: "Most gracious delivery person".

Answer (score 17):

For the general case, [*deliveryperson*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deliveryperson) may sound less informal and more respectful. For the specific case of a messenger or parcel service, you can use [*courier.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/courier)

Comment: I like "deliveryperson". As to the "courier", let's leave that to the Canadians. :) I'm pretty sure in Brooklyn, where I moved not too long ago, nobody calls a delivery guy - "courier". Even officially

Comment: We call them "couriers" here in Australia, too.

Comment: And also here in the UK.

Comment: the fact that Americans kept 'u' in 'courier' is good enough sign that you should avoid using the word within the US. :)

Answer (score 8):

For UPS, FedEx, etc., we say ***"UPS driver", "FedEx driver", etc.*** since "driver" is gender-neutral. For pizza, we say ***"pizza delivery guy"*** because that's what we've always called that person.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing gender-neutrality in a non-awkward way, but mostly for “because that's what we've always called them.” ;)

Comment: Yeah, & I call my mother "Double X" & my father "X.Y." because being "gender-neutral" is a positive Pyrrhic value in a world without substantial values. [Have I ever mentioned that I'm a cynic?]

Comment: @BillFranke, down boy! Lol!

Comment: If we don't laugh at ourselves, Kristina, we will be laughed at (What am I saying? We are laughed at!) by the rest of the world.

Comment: @BillFranke, i'm laughing at you right now! And with you, too! ;-)

Comment: I'm figuring your pizza delivered by the same woman for 20 years and you insisting on calling her a guy. Beyond awkward.

Comment: @Agos, no doubt! I guess if I ever had a pizza delivered by a female, I would have had to deal with the issue, but it's never happened yet. There's no reason "pizza driver" wouldn't work in that scenario too.

Answer (score 5):

I've always been a fan of "Courier," but I'm also  a fan of formality. 
Example: Dear FedEx Courier, I'm not home at the moment. Please leave the package by the back door. Many Thanks, etc. 
Or: Dear Pizza Courier, I've left my children with $30 for the pizza. Please keep the change. Cheers, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `I've left $30 with my children`?

Answer (score 1):

How about *UPS/FedEx/pizza **deliverer***?

> deliverer: a person who delivers goods to customers usually over a regular local route : *We eagerly took the food and tipped the deliverer*

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/deliverer)

[Ngram pizza deliverer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pizza+deliverer%2Cpizza+deliverers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpizza%20deliverer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpizza%20deliverers%3B%2Cc0)